# How to fix memory leak issue In tomcat and found what are the causes of memory leak

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks

I have deployed the code on the  tomcat server and  doing frequently updates in  war file. 
when i click on the memory leak option i got this error(Error message is given below -). To Fix it  I am restarting the server but it's not effective solution. so I want to know what i am doing  wrong in code so that i can fix it. Using maven, Spring, JPA, java 8 .

The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):

Comment: Are you trying to hot deploy by updating the webapp files ?

Comment: Yes, I am creating the  war form the  maven Install command and then manually uploading that war on the  tomcat using tomcat web interface.

Comment: Normally Tomcat produces a complete list of the offending threads and thread locals that the leak detection identified, I believe it end up in the log. Post that and we can help.

Comment: Typically this happens if you (or a 3rd party library) starts threads, or thread pools, and these are not synchronised with the application lifecycle. Spring has excellent lifecycle management (LifeCycle/SmartLifeCycle interfaces), that should be used to manage threads and pooled resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jvisualVM.exe as find the path specified for the JAVA_HOME in tomcat server's catalina.bat/catalina.sh file.

Once you start the jvisualVM, in that go the process with PID which you tomcat is running on. After that, you can got to Monitor or Profiler tab, where you will get to know how much processing is your tomcat taking and how many internal processes are running within the JVM.